# Стили input type="file"

Tags: html, файлы, css, javascript

Возможно ли в поле типа `<input type="file"/>` редактировать кнопку и само поле ввода отдельно, исключительно методами css, без js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот эти ссылки могут быть полезны для Вас:

1. [Кастомизация input type="fyle" с помощью CSS](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/css/56944/)
2. [Кастомизация input[type=file]](http://demiart.ru/forum/journal.php?user=698792&print=165671)
3. [стили для html input file](http://www.askdev.ru/question/3689/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-html-input-file/)